# How to change the location of an updated or newly downloaded App in iTunes?

Tags: windows, itunes

Backstory: iTunes 10.3.1.55 had been installed on Windows Vista 32 bit. It's main purpose is to allow me to move files to my iPod Touch 3rd Generation. Whenever I download an app, it get downloaded to the location "C:\Users\Thomas\Music\iTunes\iTunes Media\Mobile Applications".

Arc: Because my C: drive was getting full, I created two folders in my D: and moved all my apps from the one default folder in the C: drive to the two folders in the D:. Now, when an app gets updated by iTunes, the update still get saved to the default folder. I am left with both versions of the file; one in C: and the other in D:.

Question: How do I get an updated or a newly downloaded app from iTunes to save to my respective folders in D:?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On windows you can't redirect only these two folders *(on OS X and Linux you can)* - BUT you can move the whole "iTunes Media" folder to D: then all updates will go there.

In iTunes "Edit > Preferences...->Advanced Section" you can change the location of the media folder - the new folder on D: doesn't need to have the name "iTunes Media", it just need to have the same structure as it had on C:.

Comment: In fact, NTFS filesystems do support a type of symlink: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896768.aspx

Comment: I'm not a hardcore windows guy (but on OS X I am) - normally you'll get a file with the extension `.lnk`  when you create an alias, and as I see the "new" junction command - it's not a build-in command. But it looks like it should be the job.

Comment: On the Mac, you also don't get a symlink when making an "alias" in Finder.

Comment: The main difference between creating an alias on Windows and Mac/Linux is that you get the extension `.lnk` added to the link/alias on Windows - on Mac/Linux you don't. This means that you on Mac/Linux can refer to the same folder name, as the moved/linked resource - on Windows you need to modify the reference, which isn't always possible if an Application is hard-coded to use a specific name.
If you mean something else about creating an alias on Mac/Linux that I'm unaware of - please correct me. Creating the alias in Finder and/or Terminal will end up with the same result.